# Geometric quotient becomes a quotient manifold when passing to rational points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, manifolds

Let $k$ be a local field of characteristc zero.  I'm interesting in understanding how morphisms of schemes of finite type over $k$ become morphisms of analytic manifolds on passing to rational points.  For example, if $Z$ is a smooth closed subscheme of $\mathbb A^n_k$, then $Z(k) \rightarrow k^n$ becomes a closed (embedded) submanifold.  This directly follows from the constant rank theorem from differential geometry and the Jacobian criterion for smoothness.

Now, let $G$ be a geometrically connected affine algebraic group over $k$ and $X$ an irreducible affine variety over $k$ on which $G$ acts.  Suppose that the geometric quotient $X/{\sim}$ of $X$ under the action of $G$ exists.  I'm using [these](https://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/BookAV/Quotients.pdf) notes for the definition of geometric quotient.  Can we say that map on rational points

$$X(k) \rightarrow (X/{\sim})(k)$$

is a submersion of manifolds, that $(X/{\sim})(k) = X(k)/{\sim}$, and that $(X/{\sim})(k)$ and is the quotient of $X(k)$ by $G(k)$ in the category of analytic manifolds over $k$?  I do not know of any references which discuss this sort of thing.

My reference for analytic manifolds over local fields is Serre, *Lie Groups and Lie Algebras*.  The following result from Serre might be useful: "If $X$ is a manifold, and $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$, there is at most one manifold structure on the quotient space $X/{\sim}$ making the quotient map a submersion of manifolds.  Then $X \rightarrow X/{\sim}$ is a quotient map in the category of manifolds."

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ acts freely? Otherwise there is no reason for $X/G$ to be smooth, and for $X(k)/G(k)$ to be a manifold.

Comment: I think the canonical counterexample to any hope for results of this sort is the adjoint action of a (non-Abelian, reductive) group $G$ on its Lie algebra $X$.  Then $X(k)/{\sim}$ contains one point for each rational nilpotent, but all nilpotents collapse to a single point in the quotient $(X/{\sim})(k)$.

Comment: For example, if $G = \mathrm{GL}_n$ with $n > 1$, then $X/{\sim}$ is the smooth variety $\mathbb A^n$ *via* the characteristic-polynomial map, but $X(k)/{\sim}$ is badly non-smooth—and, in fact, a lot of interesting geometry comes from studying its singularities.  (This is related to @abx's point about non-free actions, though I don't know if they're exactly the same issue.)

Comment: Even $G \to G/H$ for a smooth connected affine group $G$ and smooth connected closed $k$-subgroup $H$ of $G$ is rarely surjective on $k$-points, so your hope for quotients is doomed (in such cases, $G(k) \to (G/H)(k)$ is a submersion onto an open image, using suitable analytic structures). One way is to use the analytification functor to rigid-analytic spaces (has intrinsic characterization), show it  preserves smoothness (appropriately defined), and for smooth rigid-analytic $Z$ show $(Z(k), O_Z|_{Z(k)})$ is a $k$-analytic manifold by working locally on $Z(k)$ (no Zariski topology hassle!).

Comment: Can you say more about your motivation?  As stated the generality is too much (since your expectations for the effect of algebro-geometric "quotient" maps on $k$-points fail even for the nicest possibly situations), but if you can say more about your intended context of application then it could become clearer what you "really" need.

Comment: The situation I'm thinking about is, $P = MN \supseteq B = TU$ is a standard parabolic subgroup of a quasisplit group, and $U_M := U \cap M$ acts on $N$ by conjugation.  Having worked a few examples, I believe that there exists a dense stable open subset $W$ of $N(k)$, such the quotient of $W$ under the action of $U_M(k)$ has a manifold structure, and the quotient map $W \rightarrow W/ \sim$ is a submersion.  I had hoped to accomplish this by an algebraic geometry construction.